# Changing the background color of a DateTimePicker in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

In `.NET` (at least in the 2008 version, and maybe in 2005 as well), changing the `BackColor` property of a `DateTimePicker` has absolutely no affect on the appearance. How do I change the background color of the text area, not of the drop-down calendar?

***Edit:*** I was talking about Windows forms, not ASP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0625h0ta.aspx) :

> Setting the `BackColor` has no effect on
>   the appearance of the `DateTimePicker`.

You need to write a custom control that extends `DateTimePicker`. Override the `BackColor` property and the `WndProc` method.

Whenever you change the `BackColor`, don't forget to call the `myDTPicker.Invalidate()` method. This will force the control to redrawn using the new color specified.

```
const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x14;
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if(m.Msg == WM_ERASEBKGND)
    {
        using(var g = Graphics.FromHdc(m.WParam))
        {
            using(var b = new SolidBrush(_backColor))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(b, ClientRectangle);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to accept. I was hoping there were other solutions that didn't involve knowing hex values, then I forgot about this.

Comment: Thank you for this post. I am custom drawing a DateTimePicker control and this put me in the correct direction.

Comment: I tried this change under Vista (with and without visual styles) and it does not work.

Comment: @Qua did you try calling myDTPicker.Invalidate() after setting the background color?

Comment: Also can confirm that this doesn't work on Win 7 with visual styles enabled.  It did work without visual styles though.  To test, I made a simple class that inherits from DateTimePicker and copied/pasted Vivek's code.  I replaced _backColor with Color.Blue but the box was never blue when visual styles were enabled.

Comment: Any suggestions how to achieve the same for .NET Compact Framework (Smart Device) ? We don't have WndProc there.

Comment: So I tried out the code above and can also confirm that it works in Win 7, but only when "Enable XP visual styles" is unchecked (VB.NET).  Is there a similar windows message that I can "intercept" that allows me to change the color of the text?  I know the code to actually draw the text, and I have tried intercepting messages like WM_PAINT and WM_CTLCOLOR but with no good results.  If you have any suggestions that would be really awesome.  

BTW, I have tried overriding OnPaint but do not get the results I want (I can't select the date directly in the text portion of the control).

Comment: Fully disabling visual styles isn't an option for me, so I tried specifically disabling the theme on the control using [SetWindowTheme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3893711/395685), but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 5):

There is a free implementation derived from `DateTimePicker` that allows you to change `BackColor` property on change.

See the CodeProject website: [`DateTimePicker` with working `BackColor`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/DateTimePicker_With_BackC.aspx)

Comment: That is a completely lobotomized version on which you can only use the calendar dropdown to actually pick a date, though.

Answer (score 5):

Based on this CodeProject: [A DateTimePicker with working BackColor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30660/A-DateTimePicker-with-working-BackColor) (as posted above) I've rewritten a custom datepicker class (in VB.NET) which allows customizing the Background color, the TextColor and the small Image appearing next to the dropdown button.

Eg.1:

[image]

Eg.2:

[image]

To make it work just create a new class in your project with the following code and Rebuild the Solution.
A new control called `MyDateTimePicker` should now appear in the toolbox list:

```vb
Public Class MyDateTimePicker 
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
    Private _disabled_back_color As Color
    Private _image As Image
    Private _text_color As Color = Color.Black

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        _disabled_back_color = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Gets or sets the background color of the control
    ''' </summary>
    <Browsable(True)>
    Public Overrides Property BackColor() As Color
        Get
            Return MyBase.BackColor
        End Get
        Set
            MyBase.BackColor = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Gets or sets the background color of the control when disabled
    ''' </summary>
    <Category("Appearance"), Description("The background color of the component when disabled")>
    <Browsable(True)>
    Public Property BackDisabledColor() As Color
        Get
            Return _disabled_back_color
        End Get
        Set
            _disabled_back_color = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Gets or sets the Image next to the dropdownbutton
    ''' </summary>
    <Category("Appearance"),
    Description("Get or Set the small Image next to the dropdownbutton")>
    Public Property Image() As Image
        Get
            Return _image
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Image)
            _image = Value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    '''     Gets or sets the text color when calendar is not visible
    ''' </summary>
    <Category("Appearance")>
    Public Property TextColor As Color
        Get
            Return _text_color
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _text_color = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
        g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit

        'Dropdownbutton rectangle
        Dim ddb_rect As New Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - 17, 0, 17, ClientRectangle.Height)
        'Background brush
        Dim bb As Brush

        Dim visual_state As ComboBoxState

        'When enabled the brush is set to Backcolor, 
        'otherwise to color stored in _disabled_back_Color
        If Me.Enabled Then
            bb = New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor)
            visual_state = ComboBoxState.Normal
        Else
            bb = New SolidBrush(Me._disabled_back_color)
            visual_state = ComboBoxState.Disabled
        End If

        'Filling the background
        g.FillRectangle(bb, 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height)

        'Drawing the datetime text
        g.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(TextColor), 5, 2)

        'Drawing icon
        If Not _image Is Nothing Then
            Dim im_rect As New Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - 40, 4, ClientRectangle.Height - 8, ClientRectangle.Height - 8)
            g.DrawImage(_image, im_rect)
        End If

        'Drawing the dropdownbutton using ComboBoxRenderer
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(g, ddb_rect, visual_state)

        g.Dispose()
        bb.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

*Note that this class is simplified, so it has limited functionallity

Comment: This works, even in Windows 7. But It changes looks of DatetimePicker because of Combobox. Nice solution though.