# Windows 98-style progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I use Windows 7, so my progress bars all have that green look. I'd like something a little more simplistic though, perhaps something resembling the Windows 98 progress bar.

Is there a simple way to change the style of the progress bar or will I have to recreate it manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot easily get the *exact* Win98 look without a pretty drastic rewrite of the control.  But a simple flat light-blue progress bar can be had by turning off visual styles.  Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class SimpleProgressBar : ProgressBar {
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
            SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "", "");
        }
    }
    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appname, string idlist);
}
```

Comment: Or by just using an older version of comctl32.  Though I like your solution a lot better; it's probably more robust.

Comment: That is actually a really nice effect, and in fact, on Win10 it seems to nicely match the colour of a selected item in a ListBox, so it retains a consistent style.

Answer (score 1):

I like Hans' answer but there's no need to override the control's class. You can remove the Win7 style from an individual control simply by calling **SetWindowTheme** using the control's handle. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public extern static Int32 SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd,
                      String textSubAppName, String textSubIdList);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Remove Win7 formatting from the progress bar.
            SetWindowTheme(progressBar1.Handle, "", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this... on an XP machine right now... but I suspect if you turn off "Windows XP Styles" under the framework settings for your application, you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to turn it off for one element, not everything.