# Windows 7 forms effect - how to switch it off?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7, progress-bar

I have a form, originally developed to be used on XP, containing a .NET 4.0 ProgressBar control. It's part of a composite control, where I write some info on top of the bar using TextRenderer. (I didn't go for a label, because the transparency doesn't seem to work.)

I've now upgraded the OS to Windows 7, and it seems the whole look and feel of the controls has changed. The progressbar now has a kind of "swoosh" effect, a highlight that moves quickly from left to right. The problem is this animation is removing my rendered text. My app happens to update often, so the result is a blinking text on top of my status bar.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you drawing frequently enough? Where is the drawing code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893622/windows-98-style-progress-bar

Comment: A progress bar is pretty simple to implement yourself.  See this for example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/16e16d92-aaba-49b5-a636-cd4d224fd8ff/  Just add the TextRenderer.DrawText() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason you have to write the text superimposed on the bar itself instead of underneath it, as everything else does? It sounds like it would be a lot easier to read the text if it were separate from the bar. That's certainly been my experience of progress bars as a user: keep any status messages away from the graphics.

EDIT: I've just checked, and if you don't call `Application.EnableVisualStyles` it uses the very old "big blue blocks" style, as far as I can tell. Personally I find this pretty ugly - I'd recommend that you stick with the nicer visual style, but move the text.

Comment: I need the text on top because it provides a textual representation of the progress. So, for instance "20/100" written on top of a one-fifth full bar. On and screen real estate is at a premium. Thanks for the solution, I'm not really interested in it being pretty.

Comment: @Carlos: Why is it necessary to have the textual representation overlaid though, rather than below where you can keep the contrast? Glad it works as you want it to for now, but I'd still suggest changing it unless you've got some really good reason for mixing the two :)

Comment: Well, it just seems a waste of space when I can change the colour of the "filling" to green and then overlay the text. Surely that's cooler than having the text next to the bar? After all, the text and the bar are representing the same information.

Comment: @Carlos: I'd go for readability over "cool" factor, personally.

Comment: Yeah, but it's perfectly readable. I've seen other people do it, though I struggle to come up with examples. For instance if you have a long running query or installation, it often has the text on top.Thanks btw, you've been incredibly fast with getting back to me on a few occasions now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go all the way, you can remove calls to the [**`Application.EnableVisualStyles`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx) method, which enables "colors, fonts, and other visual elements that form an operating system theme."

Visual Studio typically adds a call to this method in the `Main` method of a WinForms application.