# Winforms when Application.EnableVisualStyles() added can t change progress bar color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When i ve added in Program.cs Application.EnableVisualStyles(); then i can t change progress bar color. Do you know another solution without deleting that line because it change all styles used in the app

Application.EnableVisualStyles(); it helps to disable that but it leads to styles problems

Comment: Yes, the user's preferred visual style now controls the color.  Or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893622/windows-98-style-progress-bar/3893711#3893711).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.