# How to change background color of DateTimePicker control under Windows Vista / 7

Tags: c#, .net, c++, winforms, winapi

My question is the same as the one at [Changing the background color of a DateTimePicker in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198532/changing-the-background-color-of-a-datetimepicker-in-net).  Unfortunately, the solution there doesn't work in Windows Vista/7 when visual styles are enabled.  It does work fine if I disable visual styles, but that isn't an acceptable solution for my application.

How do I change the background color of a .NET WinForms DateTimePicker under Windows Vista / 7 when visual styles are enabled?

Any answers written from a C++ / Windows API perspective are welcome as well; I am experienced enough to translate a solution from one platform to another.  I just ask it from a C# / WinForms perspective as there are a lot of developers who use it.

**Edit:** Also I should add that suggestions to owner-draw the entire control are at the very bottom of my possible list of solutions as it sounds like a ton of work. Existing efforts I've seen seem very incomplete.

Comment: You'll have to render it yourself. That's not going to be fun. Or you could use a skinning library. That's liable to involve pain too.

Comment: Given your edit to the question, I guess I'll refrain from turning this comment into an answer!

Comment: Which background? of the dtpicker "combobox" or the monthcal control that it drops down?

Comment: The combobox; I know the calendar is easy to change...

Comment: Any luck sorting this out? I have the same problem...

Comment: You aren't going to sort it out so long as you reject the only viable solution.