# Changing the border color of a DateTimePicker with ShowCheckBox property set

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker, gdi+

Changing the border color using the property of a DateTimePicker has absolutely no effect on the appearance. How do I change the border color to red for error validation if the field is empty of the datetimepicker (`showCheckbox` property **true** and the checkbox is unchecked).

Edit1: I was talking about Windows Forms. I also tried the code below, but no luck.
Edit2:  for example, DateTimePicker control `TextChanged` event or `ShowCheckbox` is an unchecked event if the text is empty, it will change the border color to red.

Edit3: https://ibb.co/T04W8M0 If the checkbox is unchecked and text area showing empty then border-color should be red in color.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30660/A-DateTimePicker-with-working-BackColor (`ShowCheckbox` is true, not set here)

[Changing the background color of a DateTimePicker in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198532/changing-the-background-color-of-a-datetimepicker-in-net/#answer-46486746) (`ShowCheckbox` is true, not set here)

```
protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

    //The dropDownRectangle defines position and size of dropdownbutton block, 
    //the width is fixed to 17 and height to 16. 
    //The dropdownbutton is aligned to right
    Rectangle dropDownRectangle = 
       new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - 17, 0, 17, 16);
    Brush bkgBrush;
    ComboBoxState visualState;

    //When the control is enabled the brush is set to Backcolor, 
    //otherwise to color stored in _backDisabledColor
    if (this.Enabled) {
         bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
         visualState = ComboBoxState.Normal;
    }
    else {
        bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this._backDisabledColor);
        visualState = ComboBoxState.Disabled;
    }

    // Painting...in action

    //Filling the background
    g.FillRectangle(bkgBrush, 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
    
    //Drawing the datetime text
    g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 2);

    //Drawing the dropdownbutton using ComboBoxRenderer
    ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(g, dropDownRectangle, visualState);

    g.Dispose();
    bkgBrush.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi @JohnG, I'm validating field is empty or not ?, if we uncheck the  checkbox datetimepicker border should be the red color with a validation message( date field should not be empty)

Comment: you are correct, ”I change the border color to red for error validation if the field is empty of the datetimepicker with showCheckbox property true”

Comment: I agree with your comments,  but I have to match some other requirements also  along with this challenge, so If the user uncheck the DTP checkbox(`showCheckbox` property) border should be in red in color with an error message box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218971/discussion-between-shivu-and-johng).

Comment: You should take a look at… [How to change DateTimePicker Color inWindows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297758/how-to-change-datetimepicker-color-inwindows-forms) .. Comment out the line `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in the program.cs.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Do you want to simply change the Border Color of the DataTimePicker Control itself?

Comment: No, it's not working when we change the border color directly. there is no property to change the border

Comment: If you're answering my question, then, yes, I know that the border Color cannot be set with normal means. I wanted to know whether you're asking how to change the border Color alone, since the code you posted is not doing that. If you want to set a border Color, there's no problem, but it's not clear what is the condition that should generate this effect.

Comment: yes, I was asking , i haven't pasted entire code, can you check with <https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30660/A-DateTimePicker-with-working-BackColor> this link, can we change the border-color here instead of back-color?

Comment: As already mentioned, there's not problem at all in drawing a border Color, the important part - the only thing that matters - is the condition that should change the color of the Border. What condition(s) are meant to change the border color? Add an example to your question: e.g., `if [this Condition], triggered in [this Context], doesn't pass validation (example of [Validation Procedure]), then the color changes to [A specific Color or a Color that can be set with a Custom Public Property]`. BTW, when you want to ping someone, prefix the nickname with `@` (e.g., `@shivu`).

Comment: A DateTimePicker cannot set a `null` value, it's not supported. If the Control is bound to a DataSource and the bound Column returns `null`, the `ValueChanged` event is not raised, thus the Value and Text properties don't change. You cannot have an empty Text either: if you set the Text to `string.Empty`, it will default to the current Date. If you want, I'll post the skeleton of a Custom Control that can be used to set a Custom `BorderColor` property, then you'll have to adapt it to meet the conditions determined by your validation procedure.

Comment: @Jimi If the checkbox is unchecked and text area showing empty then border-color should be red in color., I have edited the question added an image link there. i think you probably understand my question.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, not how you want to do it. How do you set the Text to an empty string? With a `CustomFormat` set to a white space? What is doing that and when? Or, do you actually want to draw the Text yourself, preventing the User from changing it manually? Anyway, I'll post a Custom Control that allows to set the Border Color on specific conditions: set whatever condition/criteria you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the border Color of a DateTimePicker, in case the current DateTime doesn't pass validation based on some criteria (that you have to define), you can use a Custom Control derived DateTimePicker, override its [WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc), trap [**`WM_PAINT`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) and draw a border with a Color of choice.

The code you posted, is preventing the Control from painting itself with default values. While this is not *forbidden*, you'll have to re-paint all Control's parts, including the Text selection fields (*special* fields in this case, a feature not available in C#).
The User cannot edit the DateTime Value manually (using the TextBox fields) in this case.

▶ Here, the **`ValidateDateTimeValue()`** method will validate the current DateTime Value and change the border Color if the validation procedure fails.
Adapt it to whatever conditions you actually need to verify, it's not clear what those are from the description. The Text is usually not empty, unless the **`CustomFormat`** property is set to a white space (or a Binding's `Format` event changes it in a similar way).

▶ The **`ErrorBorderColor`** public Property allows to change the color of the border that's drawn when the validation fails.

▶ The **`IsValidDateTime`** property returns the result of validation procedure.

```
using System.Drawing;

public class DateTimePickerEx : DateTimePicker
{
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
    private Color m_ErrorBorderColor = Color.Red;
    private bool m_IsValidDateTime = true;

    public DateTimePickerEx() { } 

    public Color ErrorBorderColor {
        get => m_ErrorBorderColor;
        set {
            if (m_ErrorBorderColor != value) {
                m_ErrorBorderColor = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidDateTime {
        get => m_IsValidDateTime;
        private set {
            m_IsValidDateTime = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void ValidateDateTimeValue()
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        // Validate the new Value. e.g.
        if (this.ShowCheckBox && !this.Checked) {
            // A placeholder sub-condition: the Text is can only appear empty when 
            // setting a CustomFormat  = " "
            if (this.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
        // Set the results of the validation to the property.
        // This will also set the Border Color
        IsValidDateTime = isValid;
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(e);
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated) return;
        ValidateDateTimeValue();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_PAINT:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (!m_IsValidDateTime) {
                    using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(m.HWnd)) {
                        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width - 1, this.ClientSize.Height - 1);
                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);
                    }
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```