# Custom BackColor for DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I was researching how to set the back color of a DateTimePicker in c# and came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199278/14922400).

I have created a custom control that extends the DateTimePicker control, however I get a syntax error on `_backColor` saying that `The name '_backColor' does not exist in the current context`.

Do I have to create a Color variable within my custom class or how do I get around this error?

Edit:

I am sure I am doing something so blatantly wrong here but cannot figure it out. This is my custom class at the moment:

```
class CustomDatePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    const int WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x14;
    public Color _backColor;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_ERASEBKGND)
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHdc(m.WParam))
            {
                using (var b = new SolidBrush(_backColor))
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(b, ClientRectangle);
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public new Color BackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BackColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _backColor = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I change the Color, but it still isn't working.

```
customDatePicker1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(23, 21, 32);
customDatePicker1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: `_backColor` is simply a stand-alone private Field or the backing Field of a public property used to change the BackColor property from the PropertyGrid, in the Designer.

Comment: Ok, any idea how to fix this issue then?

Comment: What issue? There's no issue. If you want to allow to change the BackColor value from the PropertyGrid, override the public `BackColor` property. When you paint the background, use the backing Field of that public property. That Field is named `_backColor` there, name it as you like.

Comment: Please see edit guys, I must be having one of those days!

Comment: @HansPassant adding that makes the control solid white with no text

Comment: The Property should be overridden: `public override Color BackColor`. What Hans is telling you should be more clear if you read the comments under the answer you linked. There's no mistake and no issue. That's how that Control works. See the other answer, below the one you're referring to.

Comment: You are hiding the base `BackColor` property using the `new` modifier but the getter still returns the `base.BackColor`, the getter should return the `_backColor` field. On other words, you are just setting the `_backColor` but not returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to change the backcolor of Datetimepicker.

Custom class:

```
public class MyDateTimePicker: DateTimePicker
{
    private Color _backDisabledColor;

    public MyDateTimePicker() : base()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        _backDisabledColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the background color of the control
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the background color of the control when disabled
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Appearance"), Description("The background color of the component when disabled")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public Color BackDisabledColor
    {
        get { return _backDisabledColor; }
        set { _backDisabledColor = value; }
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        //Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        //The dropDownRectangle defines position and size of dropdownbutton block, 
        //the width is fixed to 17 and height to 16. The dropdownbutton is aligned to right
        Rectangle dropDownRectangle = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - 17, 0, 17, 16);
        Brush bkgBrush;
        ComboBoxState visualState;

        //When the control is enabled the brush is set to Backcolor, 
        //otherwise to color stored in _backDisabledColor
        if (this.Enabled)
        {
            bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
            visualState = ComboBoxState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            bkgBrush = new SolidBrush(this._backDisabledColor);
            visualState = ComboBoxState.Disabled;
        }

        // Painting...in action

        //Filling the background
        g.FillRectangle(bkgBrush, 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);

        //Drawing the datetime text
        g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 2);

        //Drawing the dropdownbutton using ComboBoxRenderer
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(g, dropDownRectangle, visualState);

        g.Dispose();
        bkgBrush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Use it in the winform project

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDateTimePicker picker = new MyDateTimePicker();
        picker.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        this.Controls.Add(picker);
    }
```

Result:

[image]