# DateTimePicker which is Custom BackColor & CheckBox & Editable Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to Custom DateTimePicker, which can change backColor, have a CheckBox and can editable text with keyboard.

[I find this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65988486/17602699) but it can't editable with keyboard and it haven't a checkbox.

Is it possible?

Comment: `picker.ShowCheckBox = true` sorts that one out. The text can always be edited with a keyboard. Does `picker.BackColor` not do what you want?

Comment: `picker.ShowCheckBox = true` do not work(checkbox is hiding) for that solution. Also it can't editable.

Comment: Using the standard `DateTimePicker` not the one from that answer, what do you get?

Comment: If i use Standart Datetimepicker i cant change the backcolor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.